# UIScrollView and UIImageView to simulate the photo album

Tags: ios

When I try to use the `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` to simulate the photo album.I got some questions.

I add the tap gesture on the `UIImageView`. But when I tap the `UIImageView`, the image was magnified.And I cannot get the actual size of the image, so I cannot accurately calculate the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`.

So I cannot simulate the photo browser perfectly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add (much) more detail to your question - the way it is now, there's no way anybody could help you.

Comment: Check the Photo Thumbnails feature of TTCatalog https://github.com/facebook/three20 (runs fine in the landscape mode, some problems in the portrait menu). You might find interesting clues there, not sure there's an answer to the question though.

Comment: if your going to create custom album means use the custom cell and table control as per my suggestion it works fine...

Comment: I mean when use the method - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {  
 return self.photoImageView;  
}  to magnify the UImageView on a UIScrollView.When the image has a very big width and small height,after magnified the contentSize will fit the width ,so there will be many space on the height,that is to say on the y axis.Maybe I should find some things in the three20 framework.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how to get the actual size of the image, so that you can set the contentSize of the scroll view, then try this:

```
CGSize size = imageView.image.size;
```

Otherwise, please add more info to your question and some code so that we know what you have tried to do.